# How to display a customized button on a single form only?

Tags: webforms

I have created a reset button by adding a customized module (Reset) for webform. But this button gets displayed all over the site. I just want to display this button on a single webform.

Below is my Reset module code:

```
<?php
/*
 *
 *  creating  hook_form_alter()
 *
 */
function custom_example_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id) {
            $form['webform_client_form_34'] = array(
            '#weight' => 1001,    
            '#markup' =>'<input class="form-button" type="reset" value="Reset"/>',
            );
            return $form;
}
```

How should the if condition look like that I should be adding to it ?

Answer (score 3):

Find the form id first.

Assume your form id is 50 than,

```
function <module>_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (strpos($form_id, 'webform_client_form_50') === 0) {
    $form['actions']['reset'] = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => t('Reset'),
      '#weight' => 100,
      '#validate' => array(),
      '#attributes' => array('onclick' => 'this.form.reset(); return false;'),
    );
  }
}
```

OR

```
 if ($form_id == 'my_webform_client_form_id') {

Your code

}
```

---

Another method :-

In Drupal 7, you can either use hook_form_alter() or hook_form__alter(), which ever you prefer. Just make sure you get the naming and parameters right. Drupal 6 only supports hook_form_alter() however.

When you create these functions, also remember that Drupal may not always pick up on them until you've flushed the cache.

```
function mymodule_form_webform_client_form_44_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
// code here;
}
```

Please remember to clear your cache also and try to disable/enable your module also

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to do this, you need to have a if statement that looks at the form id that corresponds with your node. For example....

```
if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_34') {
  $form['webform_client_form_34'] = array(
    '#weight' => 1001,    
    '#markup' =>'<input class="form-button" type="reset" value="Reset"/>',
  );
}
```

Comment: Not working ,the button still displaying all over other locations throughout the site .

Answer (score 2):

To further complete/complement [Shawn's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/158470/28275) (and the comment like "not working"), make sure you use the correct value for the `$form_id`.

To actually find this correct value, there are a few options, like:

- insert a line like `dpm($form_id);` in front of the if statement.
- use the [Get Form ID](https://www.drupal.org/project/get_form_id) module to easily find out form id of any form in Drupal, for which a [video demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPMB8g-CHc4) is available also. Here is a quote about it from its project page:

  > By hovering over any form you will see a contextual link available. By expanding the link you will see the form ID. Click on the link and you will see a modal window with copyable form id and hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() hook suggestion.
- Use the improved and rebranded version of the (deprecated) [Get Form ID](https://www.drupal.org/project/get_form_id) module, which is the [Devel form debug](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_form_debug) module, and for which a [video demo](https://youtu.be/CtWforq-iQQ) is available. Here is a quote about it from its project page:

  > By hovering over any form you will see a contextual link available. By expanding the link you will see the form ID. Click on the link and you will see a modal window with copyable form id and hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() hook suggestion.

After finding out the (for sure) correct value, I'd be curious if combining it with [Shawn's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/158470/28275) you can get it to work ...